# How to install legacy telepresence version on mac os

Tags: homebrew, telepresence

I installed the newest release of telepresence by

```
brew install datawire/blackbird/telepresence
```

However my scripts are using some legacy telepresence commands that are no longer supported -

```
The following flags used don't have a direct translation to Telepresence: --serviceaccount --also-proxy --also-proxy --also-proxy --also-proxy
```

I have not been able to find a way to install an old version of telepresence on mac os.

My preference would to be to use brew but this does not look possible.

Comment: How is this related to zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
brew install telepresence-legacy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
brew unlink telepresence
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datawire/homebrew-blackbird/1797069a468a4b056edbfcaf63e9ac665470cdaf/Formula/telepresence.rb
brew install ./telepresence.rb
```

I found this here
[installing-old-version-telepresence-macos/](https://novinet.co.uk/blog/installing-old-version-telepresence-macos/)